# how to run test against the built image before pushing to container's registry?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kaniko

From the gitlab documentation this is how to create a docker image using kaniko:

```
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
  only:
    - tags
```

but I want to run the test first(pytest) before pushing it to the container registry. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can simply add a `test` job before the build, which would use the correct python image, install and run pytest, and even optionally store the coverage. Some good examples in this [blog post](https://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/setting-up-gitlab-ci-for-a-python-application/) or [the official doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script). If the tests fail, the `build` stage won't be run and your image not created.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to run the tests inside the Docker container you are building the image for.

The best solution I came up with so far is

1. add the tests as another stage in a multi-stage `Dockerfile`
2. in your `test-image` job, run Kaniko without pushing the image at the end (this will run your tests during the build of the image)
3. in the `build-image` job, run Kaniko with pushing the image and specify the stage/layer of the image you want to push using the `--target` directive

Here is an example:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - >-
     echo "{\"auths...}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
  script:
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context $KANIKO_BUILD_CONTEXT
      --dockerfile $DOCKERFILE_PATH
      --destination $IMAGE_TAG
      --target image
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu as image

RUN apt update -y && \
    apt upgrade -y
    
RUN apt install -y git



FROM devimage as test

# smoke test to see whether git was installed as expected
RUN git --version

# you can add further tests here...
```

This will run the tests in a second stage within the Docker build. This would be the place where you can also install test frameworks and other test-only resources that shouldn't make it into the image pushed to the container registry.

Kaniko won't push the image, if the tests fail.