# How to validate kaniko build image

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kaniko

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613353/how-to-run-test-against-the-built-image-before-pushing-to-containers-registry) to build a docker image using `Kaniko` in `Gitlab`.

```
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

I have a use case where I need to create a container and run a python unit test once the image is created as part of the same build process. I want to run a docker command against built image by creating one container from the created image. Here is a related stackoverflow post, but, was not answered - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63613353/how-to-run-test-against-the-built-image-before-pushing-to-containers-registry)